# Regular expression to find characters in a string and convert them to a number

Tags: vb.net, regex

I may have a string for example `potato` in a vb.net application. I want to find all the occurrences of `o` and convert them to `0`, so the desired out is: `p0tat0`.

I know it can be done by the provided string operations but I need a regular expression in my scenario.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you "need" a regex in your scenario?

Comment: @Aillyn - Seems like a ridiculous constraint to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No regexp required.

```
Dim r As String = "potato".Replace('o', '0')
```

but......

```
Dim r As String = Regex.Replace("potato", "o", "0")
```

Comment: For the regex it's simply `"o"`; no need for the trailing `*` in this case (that actually gives a totally different result).